# Export PATH command - 'export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH'

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have installed anaconda in my Linux to import python packages.

After installed anaconda, I could't use anaconda in python and after some search I found that typing this command I was abled to use conda packages:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Would I like to understand exactly why do I have to do that? 
And would I like to know if is there a way to turn by default my python with anaconda packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just type `ls` at the command line, how does the shell know whether you want to run `/bin/ls`, or `/usr/bin/ls`, or `~/bin/ls`? It doesn't; it simply looks at the directories stored in your `PATH` variable, one at a time, and executes the first `ls` that it finds.

Adding `~/anaconda3/bin` to the front of your path ensures that when you type, say, `pyflakes` or `python` at your prompt, you will run `~/anaconda3/bin/pyflakes` or `~/anaconda3/bin/python` instead of generating a "command not found" error or running `/usr/bin/pyflakes` or `/usr/bin/python` instead.